# How you create confirmation link for email?

Tags: java, database, spring, email

In my project I need to send letter to user email with confirmation link.
My solution:

1. Add string column "code" and boolean column "is_active" (with default value false) to user table.
2. When user register, generate unique string key and save to database.      Send to email link, for example host.com/user/email/{code}/confirm
3. Then find by the code (generated string value) user and set flag "is_active" - true.
4. Clear value of column "code".

How are you create confirmation link for email?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I use similar practice, with the following differences:

1. I would make the URL, i.e. `host.com/user/email/{code}/confirm` secure, so that the user must login to verify himself. This ensures a bit more security. For example, if the user had typed a wrong email id while registering, that wrong person shouldn't be able to verify even after getting the mail.
2. Instead of searching by `code`, I would thus fetch the user by `id` (the id of the currently logged in user).
3. For the code, I use `UUID.randomUUID().toString()`.

Also, it depends on personal choice, but I don't use an `is_active` flag. Instead, I have a `roles` set, in which I put "UNVERIFIED" role. That helps me populating the authorities of the user a bit more easily while using Spring Security. Another way would be just to check if the `code` is `null` or not.

Comment: HEY @Sanjay not sure to understand how you can ask for user to login and search for id instead of code if account is not already created. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Sorry if this is too late. You could use [JWT](https://jwt.io/) token in your link ( example /email/{token}) good thing about JWT's is that you can sign userID inside it (can be easily decrypted but that's not the point of JWT's) but token's signature is encrypted with your secret key (and data its self) so you can validate in your backend whether that token issued by you. Also, you could add expiration time to your token so "link" is valid for a certain duration.

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't keep "{code}" as 1/0 or any predictable value. let that be a random(unique number/key generated for that user)
2. When user confirms by the link, don't just look up in db like where code=. Validate the key such any possible injection is possible or not. Or in simple words if the code logic is numeric then, the receive code  should be validated as number
3. For more security you can also put validity  for the confirmation. If the user not confirmed with in that period, then url is invalid.